# Does setitimer's ITIMER_PROF(SIGPROF)s send to every thread in Multithread and NPTL and Linux(2.6.21.7)?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Manual has said that setitimer is shared in the whole PROCESS and the SIGPROF is send to the PROCESS not to the thread.

But when I create the timer in my multithread PROCESS, unless I create independent stacks for every thread in the PROCESS to handler the signo, I will got some very serious errors in the sig handler. Through some debugging, I confirm that the stack(sole stack case) must have been reenterd.

So now I suspect that SIGPROFs may be send to multithread at the same time?  Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "create independent stacks for every thread".

Comment: The default behave is to use the pthread's stack, but My app has created a sole stack for SIGPROF handle.(SA_ONSTACK and invoking sigaltstack).

Comment: what's the glibc and kernel version you are using?

Answer (score 3):

I don't follow the details of your question but the general case is:

> A signal may be generated (and thus pending) for a process as a whole (e.g., when sent using kill(2)) or for a specific thread (e.g., certain signals, such as SIGSEGV and SIGFPE, generated as a consequence of executing a specific machine-language instruction are thread directed, as are signals targeted at a specific thread using pthread_kill(3)).  *A process-directed signal may be delivered to any one of the  threads  that  does  not currently have the signal blocked.  If more than one of the threads has the signal unblocked, then the kernel chooses an arbitrary thread to which to deliver the signal.*
>
> [man (7) signal](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal)

You can block the signal for specific threads with [pthread_sigmask](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_sigmask) and by elimination direct it to the thread you want to handle it.

Comment: Yes as you post and I have got some evidence that the way SIGPROF being handled is just like the SIGSEGV or SIGFPE. But Manual said not. So I want to know if I am wrong or the Manual.

Answer (score 0):

According to POSIX, the alternate signal stack established with `sigaltstack` is per-thread, and is **not** inherited by new threads. However, I believe some versions of Linux and/or userspace pthread library code (at least old kernels with LinuxThreads and maybe some versions with NPTL too?) have a bug where the alternate stack is inherited, and of course that will lead to crashing whenever you use the alternate stack. Is there a reason you need alternate stacks? Normally the only purpose is to handle stack overflows semi-gracefully (allowing yourself some stack place to catch `SIGSEGV` and save any unsaved data before exiting). I would just disable it.

Alternatively, use `pthread_sigmask` to block `SIGPROF` in all threads but the main one. Note that, to avoid a nasty race condition here, you need to block it in the main thread before calling `pthread_create` so that the new thread starts with it blocked, and unblock it after `pthread_create` returns.

Comment: I think this might be your issue - it seems to have been fixed sometime after 2.6.16, so it's plausible that the bug was still present in 2.6.21.